# I am able to merge multiple word documents into single document but i am not getting the formatting as like multiple word documents

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

I'm trying to merge 6 word documents into single document, I'm able to merge the all six documents but i am getting issue with the formatting and Headers and Footers.

```
Word.Application objWordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document objWordDoc = new Word.Document();
object missing = Type.Missing;
object visible = true;
object objCreateDoc = "E:\\MergeTemplates\\Temp.doc";
string strNewDocPath1 = "E:\\MergeTemplates\\Templates\\Template1.doc";
string strNewDocPath2 = "E:\\MergeTemplates\\Templates\\Templates2.doc";
string strNewDocPath3 = "E:\\MergeTemplates\\Templates\\Template3.doc";
object objPageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;

try
{

    objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(objCreateDoc, false, false, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, true,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    objWordDoc.Activate();
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertFile(strNewDocPath1, ref missing, true, ref missing, ref missing);
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertBreak(ref objPageBreak);
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertFile(strNewDocPath2, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertBreak(ref objPageBreak);
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertFile(strNewDocPath3, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    objWordApp.Selection.InsertBreak(ref objPageBreak);
    objWordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(objCreateDoc, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    objWordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

I am trying to merge multiple word documents into single word document using InsertFile().

I am able to merge it but fonts and headers & footers are mismatching. I want the same format as in the multiple documents.  Is there a way to make the styles match?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what the problem is, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: I am trying to merge multiple word documents into single word document using InsertFile(). I am able to merge it but fonts and headers & footers are mismatching. I want the same format as in the multiple documents.

Comment: Could u please help me out to solve this issue..

Comment: I've added your clarification to the question and nominated the question for reopening.  Good luck solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select all and copy from each document and paste into a new document